# Looping through a list and finding when numbers stop increasing at the same rate

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of numbers that initially increase at the same rate. For example:

```
[0,3,6,9,12,15,18...]
```

However, when reaching a certain point in the list, the increase in value actually increases.

```
[0,3,6,9,12,15,18...150,156,162,168,174...240]
```

I want to loop over this list and create two new lists. One where the number increases by 3, and one when the numbers begin to increase by 6. However, I am not sure how exactly to write the code that detects when this change occurs.

Expected result:
[0,3,6,9,12,15,18...,147]
[150,156,162,168,174...240]

Comment: What is your question about this task?

Comment: It sounds like you have the logic figured out (loop through the list, generate two new lists, one where each consecutive element has a difference of three and another when they have a difference of 6). Is there any particular part of coding this out that you are stuck on?

Comment: Yes, figuring out how to write the code to detect when the numbers stop increasing at the same rate.

Comment: And what did you figure out?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I have a clear idea of what I want to accomplish. I am just not sure what logic to use to detect when the numbers stop increasing at the same rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def splitList(list):
    if(len(list) < 2):
        return [], []
    listX = []
    listY = []
    dif = list[1] - list[0]
    for e in list:
        if(e == list[0]):
            listX.append(e)
        elif(e - listX[len(listX)-1] == dif):
            listX.append(e)
        else:
            listY.append(e)
    return listX, listY
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this?

```
test_list=[0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,27,33,39,45] #=== List 
list_3=[]
list_6=[]
new_list=[]
for j,i in enumerate(test_list): #=== Gives index number for each element in the list
    try: #== Check for exceptions, if one occurs, goes to 'except:' statement
        op=test_list[j+1] #== Get the elements from index position 1 ahead of the current ome
        if op-3==i: #== check if the the difference is 3
            
            list_3.append(i)
        elif op-6==i: #== check if the the difference is 6
            
            list_6.append(i)
    except:
        pass
new_list.append(list_3)
new_list.append(list_6)
print(new_list)
```